# Codova phonegap app giving network connection error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have built an app using phonegap build with codova 6.3.1 . But whenever i try to run it on my android device it gives me network connection error. Earlier i was executing this config.xml with codova version 3.3.0 . it was running ok.

This is my config.xml file code

```
<name>Crazedo</name>
<description>Makes Human Crazy</description>
<author email="adtsalvation@gmail.com" href="https://crazedo.com">ADT Salvation</author>

<preference name='phonegap-version' value='5.0.0' />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

<preference name="orientation"                value="portrait" />       <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="com.simplec.plugins.localnotification" />

<icon src="icon.png" />

<icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />    
<icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />

<icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi/Icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi/Icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi/Icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-xdpi/Icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

<gap:splash src="splash.png" />

<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/drawable-ldpi/splash.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/drawable-mdpi/splash.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/drawable-hdpi/splash.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/drawable-xdpi/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="680" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Deafult-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

<content src="https://crazedo.com" />
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Comment: Network connection errors could be caused by a lot of things other than just your config, could you provide some more information? Screenshots and error messages?

Comment: @Deep Did you gotta cordova whitelist plugin installed?

Comment: can we see the error message?